# Unable to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, release-upgrade

I cannot find reference to the new release (12.04) in the update manager (it was there, now no longer), while

```
mark@Athene:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

although I am running 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check your system with `cat /etc/issue`. Is it really 11.10?
2. Use Update Manager: `update-manager -d`.

Answer (score 0):

Try in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`
and then : 
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Enter the  `Update Manager` , select `Settings` and in the `Updates` make sure to select  `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version`.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

type:

```
sudo do-upgrade-release -d
```